# Faster way to use If/Else conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have up to 40 If/ElseIf conditions, where the code is:

```
   If b = 1 Then
       d = XXXX
    ElseIf b = 2 Then
       d = YYYY
    ElseIf b = 3 Then
       d = AAAA
    ElseIf b = 40 Then
       d = ZZZZ
    End If
```

Is there a faster way of doing this, so that I don't have all the If/ElseIf conditions?

Comment: A look-up table?

Comment: If you mean faster run time, 40 is really not a big number. Any update would not be faster. Or you mean coding time?

Comment: @Vityata indexing through a `static` array will go faster, especially for larger arrays. Notice, it's a *space-vs-time* tradeoff ;)

Comment: @A.S.H - with `40` examples the speed difference cannot be noticed. But in general - yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an array

remember that arrays are by default 0 indexed, although you can override that and use any indexes you want when you redim the array.

```
Dim MyArray()
Dim ind As Long
MyArray = Array("XXXX","YYYY","AAAA","ZZZZ")
ind = 2
MsgBox MyArray(ind)
```

this will return the 3rd element or AAAA

just change ind to whatever element you want to return

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use an array?

So `arr(1) = XXXX` and `arr(2) = YYYY`

That way you can

```
d = arr(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to index through some array. In order to avoid creating the array each time you need it, you can declare it with the keyword `Static`. This way, indexing is very fast (especially for larger arrays). It's kind of a *space-time tradeoff*: the array keeps present in memory but indexing it is extremely fast.

In the following, I create a function that uses a static array to convert an index to a `String`. Note, however, that you might be interested in making it more dynamic by putting the strings in some hidden worksheet and load them from there.

```
Function myString(ByVal index As Long) As String
    Static ar As Variant ' <-- static: filled once and keeps valid between function calls
    If IsEmpty(ar) Then ar = Array("XXXX", "YYYY", "AAAA", "ZZZZ")
    myString = ar(index - 1)
End Function

Sub TestIt()
  Debug.Print myString(1)
  Debug.Print myString(4)
End Sub
```

Comment: The common theme?  Arrays.  They are in readily accessible memory and can be accessed much more quickly than the machine can read a line of hard code or cell contents.  Always use arrays with large amounts of data and crunching.  But with smaller things, like less than 40 pieces of data - the time difference isn't going to matter.

Comment: @JohnMuggins, for 40+ arrays it is both faster and yields better readability/maintainability. Now *"time difference isn't going to matter"* depends on the use case. In general, code optimization (with regard to speed or any other aspect) do not matter  **until** they matter. If this indexing is done inside an intensive loop then it wil matter. If it is just to get a string and display it in an interactive application, then it wont matter even with a 1M+ different values.

Comment: And when someone asks a question on SO about that, I suppose that it *does* matter, otherwise I would advice them to keep going with the existing `if-else-if-else-if...`

Comment: 40 pieces of data can be picked out of cells about as quickly as you can put them into an array and process them.  But yes, IF there is an intense loop, where there are 5000 iterations of processing the same 40 pieces of data than certainly arrays are going to be much quicker. I think that was pretty clear as @Vityata 4 told you above. "with 40 examples the speed difference cannot be noticed. But in general - yes".

Comment: @JohnMuggins *"40 pieces of data can be picked out of cells about as quickly as you can put them into an array and process them"* --> I think you missed the idea of using a `static` array in my answer ;)

Comment: I see now.  Yes.  If the coder wants to take the time to initialize the elements of the array by hard coding then yes, it would be faster for the user.  I agree.